# How to change the value of variable from actor Y by the blueprint of actor X?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I have a project, and it has: 1 NPC (**actor X**), 2 target points and 1 tower (**actor Y**).

**Image of components in level:**

[image]

These rose arrows demonstrate part of the NPCs path.

**I added a Event Begin Overlap in the blueprint of the NPC so that when it collides with the tower it loses 10 of life every second:**

[image]

**Image of print of variable life:**

[image]

When the NPC gets 0 life, it goes to the next target point.

But I would like to know how to also modify the life of the tower by the same blueprint (NPC).

The code is already in my mind, it is kind of obvious to speak the truth.

**"Code" of NPC blueprint:**

[image]

I do not want to have to create a new Event Begin Overlap on the blueprint of the tower.

And I think using the blueprint level would not be a good idea.

One of the links below indicated something like **Blueprint Interface**, but I'd like to know if I can do what I want for the NPCs own blueprint.

**Links:**

https://forums.unrealengine.com/international/brazil/89438-pegar-vari%C3%A1vel-de-outro-blueprint

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/21386/communication-between-2-blueprints.html?sort=oldest

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/24773/how-to-call-a-blueprint-variable-from-another-blue.html

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Blueprints/UserGuide/Types/Interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The simplicity won!**

I had given up for a moment to solve this problem and I went to learn other things.

Viewing this video about arrays (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0otLohaPkXk&list=PLnwVxZ2WVVpl1sOPaEzK--4fXzq2ZQvE-&index=44), I can develop a very simple solution to my problem.

**Just add a Custom Event to the Tower blueprint:**

[image]

**In the NPC blueprint, after the Cast To Tower just call and write the name of the Custom Event:**

[image]

Another way, which would be what I thought at the time I asked the question.

**Also using the Cast To Tower (NPC blueprint):**

[image]

To be able to use the result in the While Loop.

From this second method you do not need to create an Custom Event.